# BeautifulSoup - return header correspondent to matched footer

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using `Beautifulsoup` to retrieve an artist name from a blog, given a specific match of music tags:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('http://musicblog.kms-saulgau.de/tag/chillout/')
html = r.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

Artist names are stored here:

```
header = soup.find_all('header', class_= "entry-header")
```

and artist tags here:

```
span = soup.find_all('span', class_= "tags-links")
```

I can get all headers:

```
for each in header:
    if each.find("a"):
        each = each.find("a").get_text()
        print each
```

And then I'm looking up for 'alternative' and 'chillout' in the same footer:

```
for each in span:
    if each.find("a"):
        tags = each.find("a")["href"]
        if "alternative" in tags:      
            print each.get_text()
```

the code, so far, prints:

```
Terra Nine – The Heart of the Matter
Emmit Fenn – Blinded
Amparo – The Orchid Glacier
Alpha Minus – Satellites
Carbonates on Mars – The Song of Sol
Josey Marina – Ocean Sighs
Sunday – Only
Some Kind Of Illness – The Light
Vesna Kazensky – Raven
James Lowe – Shallow

Tags Alternative, Chillout, Indie Rock, New tracks
```

but what I'm trying to do is to return only the entry correspondent to the matched footer, like so:

```
Some Kind Of Illness – The Light
Alternative, Chillout, Indie Rock, New tracks
```

how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for article in soup.find_all('article'):
    if article.select('a[href*="alternative"]') and article.select('a[href*="chillout"]'):
        print(article.h2.text)
        print(article.find(class_='tags-links').text)
```

out:

```
Some Kind Of Illness – The Light
Tags Alternative, Chillout, Indie Rock, New tracks
```